# Infragistics 13.1 to 15.2 - compilation errors

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

Trying to migrate code of a huge project that uses Infragistics 13.1 to 15.2 using the Version Utility. Getting compilation errors like this:

Error   5   The best overloaded method match for 'Prism.Modules.Common.IXamDockManagerInstance.setXamDockManagerInstance(Infragistics.Windows.DockManager.XamDockManager)' has some invalid arguments   C:\dev\Prism\Branches2010\sprint_9_12\PrismWPF\PrismApplicationHost\Shell.xaml.cs   68  17  Prism.ApplicationHost

Error   6   The type 'Infragistics.Windows.DockManager.XamDockManager' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'InfragisticsWPF4.DockManager.v13.1, Version=13.1.20131.1009, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb'.  C:\dev\Prism\Branches2010\sprint_9_12\PrismWPF\PrismApplicationHost\Shell.xaml.cs   68  17  Prism.ApplicationHost

Error   7   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Infragistics.Windows.DockManager.XamDockManager [c:\Program Files (x86)\Infragistics\2015.2\WPF\CLR4.0\Bin\InfragisticsWPF4.DockManager.v15.2.dll]' to 'Infragistics.Windows.DockManager.XamDockManager'   C:\dev\Prism\Branches2010\sprint_9_12\PrismWPF\PrismApplicationHost\Shell.xaml.cs   68  67  Prism.ApplicationHost

I am new to everything - C#, Infragistics, and the project itself. I am not new, however, to programming, know about how APIs work, and in general have a couple of years of experience developing software. Just no experience migrating =)

Please point me in the right direction with regards to how to solve this issue. I have been trying to research this but did not find anything that would help.

I have done basic troubleshooting, only have Infr. 15.2 installed at the moment, but tried upgrading when both 15.2 and 13.1 were installed. Errors do not seem to be related to what's installed. Before upgrading, the project compiles and runs well.

Comment: Did you update the app.config? Are there any setting in the app.config in the assembly section?

Comment: Alright, I have done a bunch of research, it has got something to do with the selecting the correct versions of the software that I am upgrading to, references in the project, and a bunch of other things that I have to get right. When I get one thing right, another one breaks. Will keep you posted

Comment: I would make sure that all of the Infragistics references have the correct path and none are pointing at your 13.1 folder anymore. Some .dlls don't have direct upgrades and so they might be lingering in the wrong path, which might confuse the application on which version of Infragistics you're really using.

Comment: ^ Thanks for the comment, yes, I had to manually adjust some of the references, now there are a lot of errors regarding type mismatches. So the API has changed significantly from 2013 to 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of all errors was the fact that one of the methods changed one of its argument types, a few code edits fixed the problem. More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34143214/infragistics-15-2-worksheetimage-setboundsintwips-compilation-error)