# Infragistics 15.2 WorksheetImage.SetBoundsInTwips compilation error

Tags: c#, infragistics

I have the following code

```
System.Drawing.Image logo = ... (getting logo)
WorksheetImage worksheetImage = new WorksheetImage(logo);
worksheetImage.PositioningMode = ShapePositioningMode.DontMoveOrSizeWithCells;

// Original code (works with Infragistics 13.1)
Rectangle imageRect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 10 * logo.Width, 10 * logo.Height);
worksheetImage.SetBoundsInTwips(worksheet, imageRect, true); // Breaks here
```

The following code works with Infragistics 13.1 library. However, when migrating to 15.2, compiler spits out an error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'Infragistics.Documents.Excel.WorksheetImage.SetBoundsInTwips(Infragistics.Documents.Excel.Worksheet,
>   System.Windows.Rect, bool)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Rectangle' to
>   'System.Windows.Rect'

So basically it says that the second argument should be of type System.Windows.Rect and not System.Drawing.Rectangle. The information [here](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2015.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Documents.Excel.v15.2~Infragistics.Documents.Excel.WorksheetShape~SetBoundsInTwips(Worksheet,Rectangle,PositioningOptions).html#) indicates that the type I am passing in is correct, but compiler disagrees. Why is that the case?

Comment: The both the project using 2013 and the project using 2015 reference WPF libraries (in particular, InfragisticsWPF4.Documents.Excel.13.1 & InfragisticsWPF4.Documents.Excel.15.2). But as per the answer below, this could be a good hint. Looking into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Infragistics WindowsForms Excel engine's SetBoundsInTwips method indeed uses System.Drawing.Rect as one of its parameters. However the WPF [implementation](http://help.infragistics.com/Doc/WPF/current/CLR4.0/?page=InfragisticsWPF4.Documents.Excel.v15.2~Infragistics.Documents.Excel.WorksheetImage~SetBoundsInTwips(Worksheet,Rect,Boolean).html) uses System.Windows.Rect. If this call doesn't compile then you are probably using the WPF library. Please check the references of your project and see if they use the WPF Assembly (InfragisticsWPF4.Documents.Excel.v15.2) and substitute it with the WF one (Infragistics4.Documents.Excel.v15.2).

Comment: Looking into it. That's a very good advice, actually. At first glance, it seems like it it needs to use WPF4, because that's what previous version uses, and everything works fine. Anyway, the problem is somewhere there, I will accept your answer if it will lead me to the solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the issue has been resolved - apparently the method SetBoundsInTwips in WPF in Infragistics 15.2 takes Rect as oppose to Rectangle in 13.1, so changing Rectangle to Rect did the job.